# Match any GET path with Mojolicious::Lite

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I’d like to match any GET request in Mojolicious::Lite. The code looks like this:

```
get '.*' => sub {
    my $self = shift;
    $self->render(text => 'Nothing to see here, move along.');
};
```

This dies with “Modification of non-creatable array value attempted” at MojoX::Routes::Pattern.pm, line 301. I tried other arguments to `get`, like `qr//`. That works for `/`, but does not match `/foo`. I also tried to peek at the source, but I’m none the wiser. Are you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want:

```
get '/(*restofpath)' => ...
```

(The `restofpath` is a name that will allow you to retrieve the actual pathname later, should you need it...). For more details, look at the documentation for [wilcard placeholders](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Mojolicious/lib/Mojolicious/Lite.pm).