# How do I match all routes in Mojolicious?

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I'm trying to use a Mojolicious one-liner to display a message to users about a service outage. I'd like the message to display regardless of the route. Here's what I have which is slightly modified from [what's in the documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/ojo#a).

```
perl -Mojo -E 'a("/" => {text => "The service is down for maintenance."})->start' daemon
```

That works for `/` but not anything else. I added an asterisk to turn it into a wildcard route.

```
perl -Mojo -E 'a("/*" => {text => "The service is down for maintenance."})->start' daemon
```

That matches all routes except for `/`. Is there a way to match all routes in a single definition?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Match any GET path with Mojolicious::Lite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3045799/match-any-get-path-with-mojoliciouslite)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. Try these examples:

```
perl -Mojo -E 'app->routes->get( "/" => { text => "start" }); app->routes->get( "/*any" => { text => "any" }); app->start' get /

perl -Mojo -E 'app->routes->get( "/" => { text => "start" }); app->routes->get( "/*any" => { text => "any" }); app->start' get /some_route
```

Here you define catch all route `*any` after the specific one `/`
[Documentation](https://docs.mojolicious.org/Mojolicious/Guides/Routing#Wildcard-placeholders)

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
perl -Mojo -E 'a("/*any" => {text => "The service is down for maintenance."})->start' daemon
```

I think it works for all urls but '/'.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a named placeholder, with a default value of anything, I believe it does what you want:

```
perl -Mojo -E 'a("/*x" => { text => "The service is down for maintenance.", x => ''})->start' daemon
```

May not be the prettiest code you'll ever see, but it's only a few more characters :-)